# How to determine if subject is of type X Y Z or None

Tags: rdf, sparql

This question seemed easy to me until I tried it... but it's also possible that I'm just thinking about the problem incorrectly.

Let's say we've arbitrarily gotten 100 subjects out of dbpedia.

```
SELECT ?s
WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
LIMIT 100
```

What I'd like to do is add a column that says whether they are a Person, Place, or SomeOtherType, and if none of those things, "null".

So, there are a couple ways I've tried to approach this:

1. using `rdf:type` and `VALUES`:

   ```
   SELECT ?s ?ppt
   WHERE {
     ?s rdf:type ?ppt .
     VALUES ?ppt {
       dbpedia-owl:Person
       dbpedia-owl:Place
       dbpedia-owl:SomeOtherType
     }
   }
   ```

   But this simply gets a list of subjects that have that value, and isn't necessarily answering the question of which of the three types they are (i.e. if I have 1 subject, say  in place of `?s`, I can't just add the `VALUES { ... }` block to a query against that 1 subject, because if it isn't any of the three, then there will be zero results returned.
2. I could `BIND ( IF ... ELSE ... etc ) AS ?ppt`, but that seems a bit weird, too.

So, which query functions should I use to determine which of the three (*four if you count "null"*) types something belongs to, if at all?

Comment: *Everything* is a [`Thing`](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/owl%3AThing), including persons. It’s the [super class of all classes](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/#owl:Thing).

Comment: @unor i've removed that portion of the question; its not actually relevant to what I'm asking.

Comment: Alright. I guess this topic now found its place in a separate question: [How to differentiate between a Thing and an inanimate object with SPARQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22304146/1591669)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a solution with `bind( if(...), ..., ...)` makes sense here.  It doesn't feel particularly strange.  Suppose you have data like this, where `:A` and `:B` are the types of interest.

```
@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22289078/1281433/> .

:i1 :name "i1" . # no type
:i2 a :A .       
:i3 a :B .       
:i4 a :A, :B .   
:i5 a :C .       
:i6 a :B, :C .
```

I've intentionally added some corner cases to clarify what happens. Since `:i1` has no type at all, we won't see it in the results.  Since `:i2` and `:i3` each have one "type of interest" they each appear in the results once.  `:i4` has *both* types of interest, so it will appear in the results twice, once for each interesting type.  `:i5` has no type of interest, so it will appear with an empty type (I used an unbound variable, a technique discussed in an answers.sematicweb.com question and answer, [Binding a variable only when another is non-blank?](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/26813/binding-a-variable-only-when-another-is-non-blank)).  `:i6` has a type of interest and an uninteresting type, so it will appear once with an interested type, and once with a blank value.

```sql
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22289078/1281433/>

select ?i ?type where { 
  ?i a ?_type . 
  bind( if( ?_type in (:A, :B), ?_type, ?noType ) as ?type )
}
```

```
--------------
| i   | type |
==============
| :i2 | :A   |
| :i3 | :B   |
| :i4 | :A   |
| :i4 | :B   |
| :i5 |      |
| :i6 |      |
| :i6 | :B   |
--------------
```

Comment: about that condition in which i6 has a null and a type `:B` -- please look at the result of this query, is this what is happening? http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fs+%3Ftype%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fs+a+%3F_type+.%0D%0A++BIND%28+if%28+%3F_type+in+%28dbpedia-owl%3AAgent%2C+dbpedia-owl%3APlace%29%2C+%3F_type%2C+%22null%22%29+as+%3Ftype+%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit+100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on

Comment: @Kristian The result of what query?  I see the results, but I don't have a way to get the query from it… Can you put it pastebin or something?

Comment: Sorry: `SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?type
WHERE {
  ?s a ?_type .
  BIND( if( ?_type in (dbpedia-owl:Agent, dbpedia-owl:Place), ?_type, "null") as ?type )
}
limit 100`

Comment: @Kristian That's exactly what's happening.  If you browse the data, e.g., see http://dbpedia.org/page/Daniel_Webster, you'll notice that while Webster has `rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Agent`, there are a bunch of types that are neither `dbpedia-owl:Agent` nor `dbpedia-owl:Place`.  For those types, you'll get `"null"` results.